# Unity3d Web Player for 64-bit Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, unity3d

I have followed instructions for uninstalling/reinstalling the Unity 3D Web Player, and when I go to the download site using Chrome 64-bit where it detects your Unity version, it still shows Not Installed.  If I visit the site from IE it detects my Unity Web Player version as 4.5.3f3.

I am using the 64-bit version of Chrome, which was only released recently.  Unfortunately I can't find anything that indicates whether 64-bit Chrome is supported or not.

Is it possible to get Unity3D to work with 64-bit Chrome?  I believe this might be because 64-bit Chrome AFAIK doesn't support NPAPI yet.  Does Unity3D still rely on NPAPI?

Note I am asking this a user of the Web Player.  Not as a programmer trying to develop a Unity3D application.

Answer (score 3):

Google Chrome has removed NPAPI support, not planning to add it. In the release of 64-bit Chrome, they also completely removed NPAPI. They have been gradually removing it since the beginning of 2014 by blocking most plugins except the most used ones, including Unity Web Player. Just recently they have completely removed it all. You will not be able to play Unity Web Player in Chrome until Unity releases Unity 5.

Read this:
http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html

Answer (score 0):

This 64 bit web player worked for me on 64 bit chrome. Hope it works for u as well :).
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/64-bit-webplayer-availability.153599/

Comment: [Not anymore apparently](http://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/32pgb1/chrome_42_release_disables_unity_web_player/) :|